# Non-Ebuild Programs on Gentoo

Tags: software-installation, gentoo

I like the "compile it yourself" philosophy that Gentoo runs on, but how is the support for non-ebuild programs?  That might just mean binaries, but also programs in general that were not acquired through Emerge.

Is it a big problem when the actual stuff installed on the system gets out of sync with Emerge's bookkeeping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such software usually better to install in separate tree, such as your home directory or `/opt`. In general, things may gone bad if you will install software manually in the same directories as portage. Most obvious problem - conflicts, when your software overwrites files from some package or vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

I install *custom packages* in the `/usr/local` tree. No *official packages* should be installed there, so you should be able to experiment without consequence.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Paludis](http://paludis.pioto.org/), which is an alternative package manager for Gentoo.  It offers good support for manually installed programs through the [cave import](http://paludis.pioto.org/clients/cave-import.html) command.  Here's a [blog entry](http://ciaranm.wordpress.com/2008/05/20/managing-unpackaged-packages-or-whats-this-importare-thing/) about the `importare` client, which was what `cave import` was called in older versions of Paludis.  The new command works pretty much the same way.

Comment: In the `cave import` help, when it says "Import a package from a directory containing its image", by "its image" does it just mean a collection of files that will comprise the new package?

Comment: @Faheem, yes. For a simple example, if you wanted to install `/usr/bin/foobar`, you could create `/tmp/img/usr/bin/foobar` and then import `/tmp/img`.  The usual method is to use `make install DESTDIR=/tmp/img`.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. I personally would have used different terminology in that help page.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to manually manage a package (as opposed to creating a custom ebuild in your own overlay, which is to be preferred) that is required by others, what you can do is to uninstall that package and then put it in `/etc/portage/package.provided`. That way portage will "know" it's there and dependencies will work with it. In general though it's much easier to either have a custom ebuild or for small changes use [`/etc/portage/env/...`](http://dev.gentoo.org/~zmedico/portage/doc/ch01.html). That way you can have portage work for you.